# Do all members of one family wear the same family crest on their chest?

Tags: dc, dc-extended-universe, man-of-steel

If General Zod had a son, would the symbol on his chest be the same as [seen in the film](https://levelseeker.files.wordpress.com/2013/07/man-of-steel-zods-men.jpg) or would he have his own?

Answer (score 4):

In short, **yes.** The symbols seen on the chests of each of the Kryptonian characters are indicators of their noble houses. Kal-el/Superman's house is the 'House of El' and is symbolised by an S-shaped squiggle. His father, Jor-El wears the same symbol throughout the film.

As the main representative of the [House of Zod](http://supermanrebirth.wikia.com/wiki/House_of_Zod), you would expect Dru-Zod (AKA. *General* Zod) to pass the symbol along to his descendants.

The [novelisation](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Man-Steel-Official-Movie-Novelization-x/dp/1781165998) concurs:

> The steel-blue suit, which had once belonged to a distant ancestor,
>   fit him perfectly. **The crest of the House of El was emblazoned in
>   crimson upon his broad chest.** A gust of Arctic wind lifted the red
>   cape that now flowed from his shoulders. The colorful outfit was like
>   nothing he had ever worn before, but felt natural upon his frame.

As a matter of interest, in the comic universe, neither of Zod's children wear the symbol of the house of Zod.

[image]

Comment: Purely as a matter of interest -Part II, to celebrate the launch of the film you were able to use the "[house symbol generator](http://www.supermanhomepage.com/images/man-of-steel-movie9/130526-Houses-of-Krypton.jpg)" to learn your noble house